# Calling variable from web.config to code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to call a "variable" from the web.config to the code behind then a button is clicked and I want the user to be redirected to the link that is on that vaiable.
I tried it this way:

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="E-leg" value ="https://google.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

Code behind(on button click:

```
    Protected Sub ELegLogin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim str As string  = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E-leg"].ToString();

'Error: Identifier expected

        Response.Redirect(Str)

'Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String
    End Sub
End Class
```

This doesn't work. I get error "**Identifier expected**" and "**Argument not specified for parameter 'Number' of 'Public Function Str(Number As Object) As String**"

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out

Comment: Where does **appSettings** locate in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `AppSettingsReader`.

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="E-leg" value ="https://google.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

code:

```
Dim reader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
Response.Redirect(reader.GetValue("E-leg", GetType(String)))
```

See more options [here](http://instinctcoder.com/how-to-read-app-config-file-in-vb-net/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `str` and a function called `Str`. VB.NET is a case sensitive language. If you want to redirect to the location represented by `str`, then make sure you pass that variable to your `Response.Redirect` call.

```
Protected Sub ELegLogin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim str As string  = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E-leg"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect(str)
End Sub
```

Note that it's never a good idea to name your variable `str` as it's not clear what it represents. Always give your variables a more semantic name, such as `eLegRedirectUrl`. And also, avoid having two options with similar names, such as a variable named `str` and a function named `Str`.

Answer (score -1):

If we assume your web.config looks something like this:

```
<appSettings>    
     <add key="ClientId" value="234234234"/>    
     <add key ="RedirectUrl" value="http://stackoverflow.com"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Then you could add the namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then:

```
string Clientid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToString();
string Redircturl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"].ToString();
```

And you are good to go.